# visual studio app center crash logging behavior

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-app-center

What happens when the Xamarin application is not connected to the internet and there is an exception that needs to be logged ? Is the SDK going to cache all the data that needs to be sent offline and sync when needed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Crashes and other logged events will be submitted as connectivity allows.